# I need a help on router in the Zend Frameowrk 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, router

I have URLs like this in my application:

http://testing.bazzar.com/real-estate/
http://testing.bazzar.com/real-estate/search/?state=&city=&subcategory=&subcategory_option=&search_cars=Search
http://testing.bazzar.com/real-estate/details/id/3/beautiful-3-bedroom-in-midtown-west.html

http://testing.bazzar.com/vehicles/
http://testing.bazzar.com/vehicles/search/?state=&city=&subcategory=&subcategory_option=&search_cars=Search
http://testing.bazzar.com/vehicles/details/id/4/2005-volkswagen-new-beetle-gls-1.8t.html

http://testing.bazzar.com/jobs/
http://testing.bazzar.com/jobs/search/?state=&city=&subcategory=&subcategory_option=&search_cars=Search
http://testing.bazzar.com/jobs/details/id/5/php-software-eng.html

I am trying to handle all these requests using a single controller called, advertisement.

For example, When an URL comes like http://testing.bazzar.com/real-estate/, it must load the advertisement/index action

http://testing.bazzar.com/real-estate/search/?state=&city=&subcategory=&subcategory_option=&search_cars=Search, It must load advertisement/search action

I tried somethign like this, but it is not working...

```
resources.router.routes.route_id.route               = "/real-estate/*"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.module     = "default"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.controller = "advertisement"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In application.ini

```
resources.router.routes.real_estate.route               = "/real-estate/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.real_estate.defaults.module     = "default"
resources.router.routes.real_estate.defaults.controller = "advertisement"
resources.router.routes.real_estate.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.real_estate.defaults.category_id = "12"
```

It is working :)